# Graphql TS1208 "Cannot compile namespaces when the isolateModules flag is provided

Tags: reactjs, graphql

[image]

I'm learning graphql and installed the library npm install graphql --save, which worked.  However, when trying out the code for the server, the keyword Query seems to be having an issue, it's telling me I need a comma. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first problem was not making sure the code within buildSchema was a string.  After realizing that...

**TS1208 "Cannot compile namespaces when the isolateModules flag is provided.**

isolateModules is a TSConfig.json option.

[image: TS1208]

If you run this code with 'node server.js' it works.

[image: Data]

The error is misleading and doesn't appear to affect anything.